# Complexity of counterexample function and bounded arithmetic

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Let $\{L^c_i\}_{i}$ be an efficient enumeration of languages in $DTime(2^{n^c})$,
e.g. clocked TMs.
Assume $EXP\not = NEXP$. 
Let $L$ be an $NEXP$-complete language and therefore not in $EXP$.

There is a diagonal function $f$ 
such that for all $c$ and $i$:
$$f(i,c) \in L^c_i \leftrightarrow f(i,c) \not\in L$$

> Can such an $f$ be in $FPH$ or $FEXP$?

Also related to the above question,

> Is $S_2+EXP=NEXP$ consistant?